# Как считать нажатие клавиш C++?

Tags: g++, ubuntu, c++, opengl

Я хочу написать простую игру на openGL, в которой будут красные точки, и синяя точка, которой вы должны собирать их, двигая синюю точку с помощью клавиш-стрелок. Притом красные двигаются быстрее, чем синяя.

На всякий случай, если не сложно, подскажите, как сделать, чтобы на экран выводилось не статичное изображение, а двигающееся? Своих вариантов нет, так как они не сработали.

Comment: Вариантов вывода "не статичного" изображения (то бишь, анимированного) всего два: 1. Вы стираете старые объекты (например рисуя их черным цветом, либо воспроизводя на их месте предварительно сохраненный элемент заднего фона), затем прорисовываете объекты в новых местах. 2. Вы перерисовываете ВСЮ картинку (возможно, просто полностью очищаете "экран" заполняя все черным, затем рисуете объекты)...

Comment: посмотрите OpenGL SuperBible, в ней среди первых примеров идет движение прямоугольника по окну приложения

Answer (score 6):

Обычно так:

1. Инициализация
2. Проверка "ввода" - т.е. нажатий клавиш, мыши и пр.
3. Получен сигнал "выхода"? - если да, к 8
4. Обсчет всех игровых объектов
5. Прорисовка всех объектов в бэк-буфере (off-screen buffer, memory surface, как угодно, "в памяти" короче)
6. Вывод прорисованного на экран.
7. Возврат к 2
8. Деинициализация, освобождение ресурсов.

Answer (score 0):

Привязывал к стрелкам на клавиатуре поворот сцены, было вот как

```
#include <GLUT.H>

#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

bool g_is_full_screen = false;
GLfloat winH = 100.f, winW = 100.f;
GLfloat xRot = 0.0f, yRot = 0.0f;
GLfloat rotationSpeed = 2.0f;

void drawAxises()
{
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(90.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

        glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(0.0f, 90.0f, 0.0f);

        glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 90.0f);
    glEnd();

    glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
}

void renderScene() {

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

    glStencilFunc(GL_NEVER, 0x0, 0x0);
    glStencilOp(GL_INCR, GL_INCR, GL_INCR);

    glFrontFace(GL_CW);

    glPushMatrix();

    glRotatef(xRot, 10.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glRotatef(yRot, 0.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f);

    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    GLubyte bitmap[] = {
            0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
            0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
            0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
            0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
            0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
            0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
            0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xc0,
            0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0xf0,
            0x00, 0x00, 0x07, 0xf0,
            0x0f, 0x00, 0x1f, 0xe0,
            0x1f, 0x80, 0x1f, 0xc0,
            0x0f, 0xc0, 0x3f, 0x80,
            0x07, 0xe0, 0x7e, 0x00,
            0x03, 0xf0, 0xff, 0x80,
            0x03, 0xf5, 0xff, 0xe0,
            0x07, 0xfd, 0xff, 0xf8,
            0x1f, 0xfc, 0xff, 0xe8,
            0xff, 0xe3, 0xbf, 0x70,
            0xde, 0x80, 0xb7, 0x00,
            0x71, 0x10, 0x4a, 0x80,
            0x03, 0x10, 0x4e, 0x40,
            0x02, 0x88, 0x8c, 0x20,
            0x05, 0x05, 0x04, 0x40,
            0x02, 0x82, 0x14, 0x40,
            0x02, 0x40, 0x10, 0x80,
            0x02, 0x64, 0x1a, 0x80,
            0x00, 0x92, 0x29, 0x00,
            0x00, 0xb0, 0x48, 0x00,
            0x00, 0xc8, 0x90, 0x00,
            0x00, 0x85, 0x10, 0x00,
            0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00,
            0x00, 0x00, 0x10, 0x00,
    };
    glEnable(GL_POLYGON_STIPPLE);
    glPolygonStipple(bitmap);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glVertex3f(-50.0f, 50.0f, 5.0f);
        glVertex3f(50.0f, 50.0f, 5.0f);
        glVertex3f(50.0f, -50.0f, 5.0f);
        glVertex3f(-50.0f, -50.0f, 5.0f);
    glEnd();

    glStencilFunc(GL_NOTEQUAL, 0x1, 0x1);
    glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP);

    glDisable(GL_POLYGON_STIPPLE);

    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
        glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(30.0f, 30.0f, 30.0f);
        glVertex3f(20.0f, 40.0f, 30.0f);
        glVertex3f(40.0f, 40.0f, 30.0f);
        glVertex3f(40.0f, 20.0f, 30.0f);
        glVertex3f(20.0f, 20.0f, 30.0f);
        glVertex3f(20.0f, 40.0f, 30.0f);
    glEnd();

    glFrontFace(GL_CCW);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
        glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(30.0f, 30.0f, 60.0f);
        glVertex3f(20.0f, 40.0f, 30.0f);
        glVertex3f(40.0f, 40.0f, 30.0f);
        glColor3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        glVertex3f(40.0f, 20.0f, 30.0f);
        glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(20.0f, 20.0f, 30.0f);
        glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(20.0f, 40.0f, 30.0f);
    glEnd();

    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);

    drawAxises();

    glPopMatrix();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void setupRC() {
    glClearColor(0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
    glClearStencil(0.0f);
}

void changeSize(GLsizei w, GLsizei h) {
    GLfloat aspectRatio;
    if (h == 0)
        h = 1;

    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    aspectRatio = (GLfloat)w / (GLfloat)h;

    if (w <= h) {

        winW = 100.f;
        winH = 100.f / aspectRatio;

        glOrtho(-100.0, 100.0, - winH, winH, 100.0, -100.0);
    } else {

        winH = 100.f;
        winW = 100.f * aspectRatio;

        glOrtho(-winW, winW, -100.0, 100.0 , 100.0, -100.0);
    }

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

void specialFunc(int key, int x, int y)
{
    switch(key)
    {
    case GLUT_KEY_UP:
        xRot -= rotationSpeed;
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:
        xRot += rotationSpeed;
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:
        yRot += rotationSpeed;
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:
        yRot -= rotationSpeed;
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_F1:
        if(g_is_full_screen)
        {
            glutReshapeWindow(400, 400);
        }
        else
        {
            glutFullScreen();
        }
        g_is_full_screen = !g_is_full_screen;
        break;
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
/*
    for console application
*/
/*
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowSize(400, 400);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_STENCIL);
    glutCreateWindow("SimpleWindows");
    glutDisplayFunc(renderScene);
    glutReshapeFunc(changeSize);
    glutSpecialFunc(specialFunc);
    setupRC();
    glutMainLoop();
}
*/

/*
    for win application
*/
int APIENTRY _tWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    //MessageBox(NULL, L"Simple Program.", L"WINAPI + OpenGL", 0);
    //glutInit(0, 0);
    glutInitWindowSize(400, 400);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_STENCIL);
    glutCreateWindow("SimpleWindows");
    glutDisplayFunc(renderScene);
    glutReshapeFunc(changeSize);
    glutSpecialFunc(specialFunc);
    setupRC();
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```